# Animated bezier curve on mulitple canvases

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, bezier

I have multiple Bezier curves that run from top to bottom and sway a little bit! As can be seen in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pw17l008/pen/oRNKpg), the curves seem to animate as they are supposed to but are not drawn as I expected them to. If I increase the size of the canvas that seems to stretch the Beziers so that after a certain height it looks fine but I can't understand by the curves are all crumpled up on a small canvas height, as they are in this example.
below is my code:

```js
function milestoneLines() {
  //get all canvases from the DOM
  const canvas = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
  console.log(canvas);
  //loop through array of canvases
  canvas.forEach(makeCanvas);

  function makeCanvas(canvas, index) {
    // get canvas width/height
    canvas.width = $(".main").eq(index).width();
    canvas.height = $(".main").eq(index).height();

    //getting the height of all milestones
    let milestoneHeight = $(".main").eq(index)
      .find('.info_wrapper');
    let totalMilestoneHeight = 0;
    milestoneHeight.each(function() {
      totalMilestoneHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
    });

    const c = canvas.getContext('2d');

    let milestoneHalfHeight = totalMilestoneHeight / 2;
    let milestoneQuarterHeight = totalMilestoneHeight / 4;
    let milestoneHalfWidth = canvas.width / 2;
    let bezEndY = $('.main').eq(index).offset().top +
      $('.main').eq(index).outerHeight();


    let bezStartY = $('.main').eq(index)
      .find(".dot").eq(0).offset().top;

    // Bezier Curve points
    let bezStart = {
      x: milestoneHalfWidth,
      y: bezStartY
    };
    let bezCp1 = {
      x: milestoneHalfWidth - 35,
      y: milestoneHalfHeight
    };
    let bezCp2 = {
      x: milestoneHalfWidth,
      y: milestoneHalfHeight + milestoneQuarterHeight
    };
    let bezEnd = {
      x: milestoneHalfWidth,
      y: bezEndY
    };

    //Line 1
    //dx = xvelocity 
    let dx1Line1 = .6;
    let dx2Line1 = .6;
    let bezCp1Line1x = bezCp1.x;
    let bezCp2Line1x = bezCp2.x;

    //Line 2
    //dx = xvelocity
    let dx1Line2 = .8;
    let dx2Line2 = .8;
    let bezCp1Line2x = bezCp1.x;
    let bezCp2Line2x = bezCp2.x;

    //Line 3
    //dx = xvelocity
    let dx1Line3 = 1;
    let dx2Line3 = 1;
    let bezCp1Line3x = bezCp1.x;
    let bezCp2Line3x = bezCp2.x;

    //Line 4
    //dx = xvelocity
    let dx1Line4 = .9;
    let dx2Line4 = .9;
    let bezCp1Line4x = bezCp1.x;
    let bezCp2Line4x = bezCp2.x;

    function bezCurve() {
      c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      //different start positions for the bezier curves
      let bufferX = 120;
      let bufferY = 120;
      let bufferStartY = 80;

      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        c.beginPath();
        if (i == 0) {
          c.moveTo(bezStart.x, bezStart.y + bufferStartY);
          c.bezierCurveTo(bezCp1Line1x - bufferX, bezCp1.y - bufferY, bezCp2Line1x + bufferX, bezCp2.y - bufferY, bezEnd.x, bezEnd.y);

          if (bezCp1Line1x > (bezCp1.x + 280) || bezCp1Line1x < bezCp1.x) {
            dx1Line1 = -dx1Line1;

          }
          if (bezCp2Line1x < (bezCp2.x - 280) || bezCp2Line1x > bezCp2.x) {
            dx2Line1 = -dx2Line1;
          }
          bezCp1Line1x -= dx1Line1;
          bezCp2Line1x += dx2Line1;
          c.strokeStyle = "red";
        }
        if (i == 2) {
          c.moveTo(bezStart.x, bezStart.y + bufferStartY);
          c.bezierCurveTo(bezCp1Line3x + bufferX, bezCp1.y + bufferY, bezCp2Line3x - bufferX, bezCp2.y + bufferY, bezEnd.x, bezEnd.y);

          if (bezCp1Line3x < (bezCp1.x - 320) || bezCp1Line3x > bezCp1.x) {
            dx1Line3 = -dx1Line3;
          }

          if (bezCp2Line3x > (bezCp2.x + 320) || bezCp2Line3x < bezCp2.x) {
            dx2Line3 = -dx2Line3;
          }
          bezCp1Line3x -= dx1Line3;
          bezCp2Line3x += dx2Line3;
          c.strokeStyle = "green";

        }
        if (i == 1) {
          c.moveTo(bezStart.x, bezStart.y + bufferStartY);
          c.bezierCurveTo(bezCp1Line2x + bufferX, bezCp1.y + bufferY, bezCp2Line2x - bufferX, bezCp2.y + bufferY, bezEnd.x, bezEnd.y);

          if (bezCp1Line2x < (bezCp1.x - 350) || bezCp1Line2x > bezCp1.x) {
            dx1Line2 = -dx1Line2;
          }

          if (bezCp2Line2x > (bezCp2.x + 350) || bezCp2Line2x < bezCp2.x) {
            dx2Line2 = -dx2Line2;
          }
          bezCp1Line2x -= dx1Line2;
          bezCp2Line2x += dx2Line2;
          c.strokeStyle = "blue";

        }
        if (i == 3) {
          c.moveTo(bezStart.x, bezStart.y + bufferStartY);
          c.bezierCurveTo(bezCp1Line4x - bufferX, bezCp1.y - bufferY, bezCp2Line4x + bufferX, bezCp2.y - bufferY, bezEnd.x, bezEnd.y);

          if (bezCp1Line4x > (bezCp1.x + 320) || bezCp1Line4x < bezCp1.x) {
            dx1Line4 = -dx1Line4;
          }
          if (bezCp2Line4x < (bezCp2.x - 320) || bezCp2Line4x > bezCp2.x) {
            dx2Line4 = -dx2Line4;
          }
          bezCp1Line4x -= dx1Line4;
          bezCp2Line4x += dx2Line4;
          c.strokeStyle = "grey";

        }
        c.lineWidth = 6;
        //c.strokeStyle = "#FCE6DF";
        c.stroke();
        bufferX = bufferX - 30;
        bufferY = bufferY - 30;
        bufferStartY = bufferStartY - 20;
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(bezCurve);
    }
    bezCurve();
  }
}
$(document).ready(milestoneLines);
```

```css
#milestone_canvas {
  position: absolute;
}

.main {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.info_wrapper {
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: solid 2px;
}

.container {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.dot {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: maroon;
  border: solid 4px green;
  z-index: 100;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.text {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <canvas id="milestone_canvas"> </canvas>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </div>
      <div class="dot "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </div>
      <div class="dot "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </div>
      <div class="dot "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </div>
      <div class="dot "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </div>
      <div class="dot "></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you turn this into a [mcve] please? Anything that's 20 paragraphs long can be made 1 paragraph long, too, while making things easier to debug, and easier to talk about.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I just did!

Comment: The code in your question has lots of repeated divs, a whole bunch of CSS that is entirely unrelated to showing the actual problem, and the JS is full of duplicate code because you're still using four lines instead of just one, which is all you need to show off the problem of "not seeing lines in the second canvs". So there is a _ton_ of code that should still be removed before this is a good [mcve]: reducing your code is an important debugging step, don't take it lightly, and don't stop before you really have "minimal" =)